# Scala, combining filters on XML node

Tags: xml, scala, filter, xmlnode

XML sample:

```
<structure-node (n)>
    <node-data (1)>
        <feature-list (n)>
            <feature (n)>
                <value (1)>123</value>
            </feature>
        </feature-list>
    </node-data>
</structure-node>
```

In brackets the max occurrences. I want to get a structure-node, but only where a containing value is equal 123.

I've tried this (Play! with Scala):

```
@{ (parentNode \ "structure-node").filter{ f => (f \ "node-data" \ "feature-list" \ "feature" \ "value").text == "123"}  }
```

But it seems like I can't filter on fields which don't exist on the node itself. Do I have to combine filters? I've tried, but failed...

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the function exists to add a condition on the SeqNode of "value" tags  under the "structure-node" tag   :

```
(parentNode \ "structure-node").filter(s => (s \ "node-data" \ "feature-list" \ "feature" \ "value").exists ( t => t.text == "123"))
```

or

```
(parentNode \ "structure-node").filter(s => (s \\ "value").exists ( t => t.text == "123"))
```

Comment: That only seems to work if there is only one feature-list and only one feature in it. I thinkg I have to filter and filter and filter again...

Comment: You can manage many occurence by the \\ selector, i have edited my answer to fix that

Comment: I know that from XSLT and already tried it, without success. Did you test it? My solution: `@{(parentNode \ "structure-node").filter( fo => fo.exists {fi => (fi \ "node-data" \\ "feature-list" \\ "feature" \ "value").text == "123" } ) }` doesn't work.

Comment: I understand why that doesn't work because if you have many occurence of feature or feature-list texts are concatened, i will check that and come back to you

Comment: Ok, that's exactly what I've meant. You only have one feature-list and one feature in it. But in <node-data> there could be n <feature-list> and in that n <feature>. And then it seems like it doesn't work.

Comment: I have edited the post with the right filtering ;) now i work on the the SeqNode of values

Comment: That works, thanks alot. It's all about the correct using of \\

Comment: i have made a mistake about \\ because we don't need it here , the \\ will  be necessary if you don't specify the intermediate nodes between the parentNode and the "value" Node, i have updated the answer with the differents  possibilities